# Lusin approximation of BV functions using Lipschitz functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, reference-request

The following theorem holds for BV functions (a reference for the proof is given in a question on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/327267/hausdorff-dimension-of-the-graph-of-a-bv-function/327310?noredirect=1#comment817269_327310).

There exists a constant $\kappa>0$ such that for every $u\in BV(\mathbb R^N)$ and $\lambda>0$ there exists a Lipschitz function $v_\lambda \in \mathrm{Lip}(\mathbb R^N)$ with Lipschitz constant $L= \lambda \kappa$  such that
$$
|x\in \mathbb R^N : u(x)\ne v_\lambda(x)| \le \frac{\kappa}{\lambda} |Du|(\mathbb R^N).
$$

**In the case $N=1$, how can we give a simple proof of the statement?**

In $1$-dimension the statement reads

> There exists a constant $\kappa>0$ such that for every $u\in BV([a,b])$ and $\lambda>0$ there exists a Lipschitz function $v_\lambda \in \mathrm{Lip}([a,b])$ with Lipschitz constant $L= \lambda \kappa$  such that
>   $$
> |x\in \mathbb [a,b] : u(x)\ne v_\lambda(x)| \le \frac{\kappa}{\lambda} T.V._{[a,b]}(u).
> $$